# Including file/module in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ from Python. When we write `#include<iostream>`, we are including a library or module. So can we write `iostream::std::cout<<`?

Comment: "So can we write iostream::std::cout<<"? Yes, but it won't compile. `std::cout << ThingIWantToPrint;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `#include<iostream>`, you tell preprocessor to put content of iostream file directly instead of that line.